# set_constrained_layout doesn't work on my code

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The following is mycode 
if use fig.set_constrained_layout(True) , legend:lga display error
if use fig.tight_layout(), legend:lga dispaly ok
could you please tell me the reason and how to use the set_constrained_layout

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)   
x2 = x1*10 
y1 = x1*2
y2 = x1*100


fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_constrained_layout(True)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,frameon=False,sharex=ax1)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2,frameon=False,sharex=ax3)

lg1 = ax1.plot(x1,y1,label='ax1')
lg2 = ax2.plot(x2,y2,label='ax2',color='tab:red')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right') 


lg3 = ax3.plot(x1,y1,label='ax3')
lg4 = ax4.plot(x2,y2,label='ax4',color='tab:red')
ax4.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right') 

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 

ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue') 
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red') 


loc_val = "upper right"

lga = lg1 + lg2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lga]
ax1.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val ,bbox_to_anchor=(2,1))

lgb = lg3 + lg4
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgb]
ax3.legend(lgb, labs, loc=loc_val )

fig.set_constrained_layout(True)
#fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to organize the layout using gridspecs (or `plt.subplots` which does the same thing).  Future versions of matplotlib will do what you want, but its present limitation that each `add_subplot` command adds a new gridspec, and they don't know anything about each other, so the layout is bad.

In your example you will want to mess with your legend placement.  Not quite sure what you were after with the bbox_to-anchor value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.arange(10)
x2 = x1*10
y1 = x1*2
y2 = x1*100


fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_constrained_layout(True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0],frameon=False,sharex=ax1)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1],frameon=False,sharex=ax3)

lg1 = ax1.plot(x1,y1,label='ax1')
lg2 = ax2.plot(x2,y2,label='ax2',color='tab:red')
ax2.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right')


lg3 = ax3.plot(x1,y1,label='ax3')
lg4 = ax4.plot(x2,y2,label='ax4',color='tab:red')

ax4.get_yaxis().set_ticks_position('right')

ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

loc_val = "upper right"

lga = lg1 + lg2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lga]
ax1.legend(lga, labs, loc=loc_val)

lgb = lg3 + lg4
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lgb]
ax3.legend(lgb, labs, loc=loc_val )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jody, very thanks for your help  , actually matplotlib is very hard for me.

Comment: Well you are trying to do something relatively sophisticated.  If the above answers your question, go ahead and mark it answered.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, now I take over code about matplotlib which is more than ten years and it is  based on matplotlib v1.x , It is a background, so I couldn't use "add_gridspec" , so  thanks anyway